How can I have a libvirt VM get IP from router on a host where docker is installed?
If I have a host that does not have Docker, I would just create a bridge network no my host and then have the VM use that and the VM would get an IP on my router/LAN.
But if I have a host that has Docker installed, this won't work because of numerous issues. See Host is getting an IP from a bridged device but a virt-manager VM is not.
So now I am wondering if there is any OTHER way to have a libvirt VM get an IP on my router even with Docker installed? Maybe another libvirt network mode or something?

What numerous issues? There's a issue mentioned in the link with numerous workarounds. Just pick one. Maybe macvtap is yet another one you can consider (not really sure whether or not it is not affected by br_netfilter). There's also DHCP relay, although that's highly unlikely what you want / a better option.

But all of the workarounds come with issues and aren't exactly idea. Docker in a VM is the best but seems like a waste of resources. :(
